# Any limitations on Active Directory users and LDAP

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap

I am currently implementing a website that have login page and authenticates users via LDAP through a web service.

I have to import 150.000 users into one OU in this LDAP. Any of them could login one day to the web site, so they need to be authenticated in LDAP.

Is there any limitation of number of users that LDAP can handle?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The P in LDAP stands for "protocol". That's all LDAP is: a protocol for communication between a directory server (like Active Directory) and a client application. Any limitation on number of accounts will not have anything to do with LDAP. It's the directory server behind the scenes that will dictate any such limitation.

If you're talking about Active Directory, the only limit is the absolute maximum number of objects (any type of objects) that can be created in the lifetime of any one domain. By default that is ‭1,073,741,823‬, but in domains running on Windows Server 2012, it can be raised to ‭2,147,483,647‬. (You can read about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/managing-rid-issuance) if you'd like)

So there is nothing stopping your from putting 150,000 users in one OU. However, it might be in your benefit to split those up into different OUs (even if those OUs are all under the one OU) so when you open an OU in AD Users and Computers (or any other management tool) it won't have to load all those users before you find what you're looking for.